# Team member plugin problem after changing to another hosting

Tags: plugins, domain, hosting

Recently I have change my wordpress site to another hosting. After changing the hosting I m facing a strange problem with one of my plugin named "Team Members".

The problem is with the admin panel of the plugin. I cannot delete a member or add a member. mouse actions are not working over the plugin window.

I inspected in chrome browser and its shows the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL                         load-scripts.php:100
Uncaught TypeError: $id(...).hide(...).farbtastic is not a function    cmb2.min.js:1
```

Comment: Try deleting your cookies from that domain and clearing cache, I hope this will help.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't help

Comment: I was just looking at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916987/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-load-scripts-php1 so I though might it help

Comment: After clearing everything i am getting additional error saying that jquery is not defined